# Remove Product Categories Block from home page in WooCommerce Storefront Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront

I am trying to remove the default product categories section block that is shown from home page in WooCommerce Storefront theme  .

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried to remove that block by using several hooks in the functions.php like for example:

```
function remove_storefront_category() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'storefront_sorting_wrapper', 9);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 30);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'storefront_sorting_wrapper_close', 31);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_reset_loop', 999);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'remove_storefront_category' );
```

But no matter what I am trying, this product categories section block won't go away.

I have searched a lot and only found information about hiding specific categories, but I want to hide it completely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As there is an answer to your question, I would expect some feed back please, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To remove from the Storefront theme home page, the product categories section, you can use the following simple code snippet:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_storefront_home_product_categories', 10 );
function remove_storefront_home_product_categories(){
    // Unhook storefront_product_categories() function from 'homepage' action hook
    remove_action( 'homepage', 'storefront_product_categories', 20 );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.